# Commands that work in vim don't work in vimrc

Tags: vim, default, startup

I'm using [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) to set up bundles in vim. One such bundle I use is [vdebug](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug). I want to set vdebug so it doesn't have a "server" option by default. Within vim, I can do that with either one of

```
VdebugOpt server ""
let g:vdebug_options['server'] = ""
```

But if I set one of those commands in my ~/.vimrc, when I first start vim it fails. Here's a very simple .vimrc that reproduces the problem:

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
call pathogen#helptags()
VdebugOpt server ""
```

With that, I get

```
Error detected while processing /home/editor/.vimrc:
line    5:
E492: Not an editor command: VdebugOpt server ""
```

Or, if I change the last line to

```
let g:vdebug_options['server'] = ''
```

I get

```
Error detected while processing /home/editor/.vimrc:
line    5:
E121: Undefined variable: g:vdebug_options
```

But once vim is started, either one of those commands works. What is going on to cause this discrepancy, and how can I set the default I want for vim on startup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see in [`:h initialization`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#initialization) that Vim will, at startup, run `.vimrc` (step 3), then run plugins (step 4). `VdebugOpt` is simply not defined in `.vimrc`, nor is `g:vdebug_options` (so you can't add a new option).

However, you can *define* `g:vdebug_options`:

```
let g:vdebug_options = {
  \   'server' = ''
  \ }
```

or equivalently

```
let g:vdebug_options = {}
let g:vdebug_options['server'] = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in another answer, plugin commands are not defined yet when the .vimrc is running. You can work around this by invoking the command in a VimEnter autocmd:

```
autocmd VimEnter * VdebugOpt server ""
```